# Use Geography PostGIS function with H2GIS

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I have this function where I get a hibernate spatial  Geometry type and buffer it in **meters** like so

```
entityManager
.createNativeQuery(“SELECT ST_BUFFER(GEOGRAPHY(:geometry), :margin, ‘join=mitre’) AS BUFFERED_GEOMETRY”)
.setParameter(“geometry”, geometry)
.setParameter(“margin”, margin)
.unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
.addScalar(“ BUFFERED_GEOMETRY”, new JTSGeometryType(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE))
.getSingleResult();
```

This code works perfectly when I use postGIS but when I use h2GIS in my tests I get a sql error

```
Function “GEOGRAPHY” not found
```

I indeed saw that this function and some others don’t exist in the H2GISFunctions.class. Is there a way around this? Except using Postgres in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know H2GIS, but PostgreSQL is almost as fast as H2 if you avoid most DDL and use `TRUNCATE` for clearing data between tests, so why wouldn't you want to test against the database that you also use in production?

Comment: This tests is part of bigger test module that is already using h2 and i really don’t want to refactor or effect all the other tests

Comment: I don't have an answer for you then. You could try to implement these H2 functions yourself though. Not sure how hard it is to implement a `GEOGRAPHY` function, but since you can use Java to implement functions in H2, it shouldn't be too hard.